# android media player streaming url doesnt work

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

Hi i have a little question I want to use mediaplayer but with the url doesnt work, it means after a lot of minutess it sounds

if (mediaPlayer == null) {
                    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

```
                try {
                    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource("http://176.31.246.109:8000/jcradio13");
                    mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
                    mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                            mp.start();
                        }
                    });
                    // mediaPlayer.prepare();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } else if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                } else if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                }

            }
```

Comment: what is your mean about doesn't work ?

Comment: what's the problem that you're facing? share the stacktrace in case you're getting some kinda error.

Comment: the problem is my audio not sound this is the url http://176.31.246.109:8000/jcradio13 but it not work